# Breadcrumb with subcategories

Tags: php

I want to have breadcrumb on my website looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pk88b9nb/

My categories table structure is like that: `id -- name -- parentid`

When i use php code below:

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
  <?php
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * from categories where id=".$_GET['id']."");
    while($r = $query->fetch())
    {
        echo "<a href=\"#\">$r[name]</a>";
    }
  ?>
  </li>
</ol>
```

outcome is: `Home / Category`.
even subcategories outcome is: `Home / Subcategory`.

**I want to make it like `Home / Category / Subcategory`**

how should i change my php code?

Comment: Please provide details of your database structure. Ie do you have a subcategories table? What is the relationship between categories and subcategories?

Comment: as i mentioned in my post: "My categories table structure is like that: `id -- name -- parentid`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the category is there is a parentid with a subquery

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <?php
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT *, (SELECT name FROM categories as s WHERE s.id = c.parentid) as category from categories as c where id= ".$_GET['id']."");
    while($r = $query->fetch())
    {
        if (!empty($r['category'])) echo "<li><a href=\"#\">$r[category]</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"#\">$r[name]</a></li>";
    }
  ?>
</ol>
```

You should also escape the `$_GET` variable in the sql query to avoid injection attacks.